# Why should I do Future.cancel() if I get InterruptedException when doing Future.get()

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

It is stated in *Java Concurrency in Practice (Brian Goetz)* (highlights are mine):

> When **Future.get throws InterruptedExcetion** or TimeoutException and you know that the result is no longer needed by the program, **cancel the task with Future.cancel**

Javadoc for Future.get states that (highlight are mine):

> throws InterruptedException - if the current thread was **interrupted while waiting**

So, as far as I understand: if I get an InterruptedException then my task hasn't been started yet (because the executing thread **was interrupted while waiting**). Then why do I have to cancel my task?

Comment: What if the task started, then was waiting for some resource, then it was interrupted?

Comment: Maybe I'm reading the javadoc wrong. It seems that it means that the thread is waiting for the task to start. Or maybe I'm wrong here.

Comment: So, does "waiting" mean that the executing thread is blocked in any of the blocking invocations in the code of my task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Waiting in

> throws InterruptedException - if the current thread was interrupted while waiting

means that the current running thread (the one executing `Future.get()`) was waiting for `Future.get()` to return. In general when a thread waits, it is like waiting to acquire an [explicit lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html), [`Object.wait()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) or for a blocking method in `BlockingQueue`.

Now about the quote from the book: if your current thread is interrupted (thus the `InterruptedException`) and you interpret this as an abrupt cancellation, that you probably do not care anymore what the future will return, so should stop whatever the future does.

So you are wrong when you tell that the Thread hasn't been started.